# QSettings how to save QMap<QString,int> into configuration file

Tags: c++, qt

After reading [Save `QList<int>` to `QSettings`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452893/save-qlistint-to-qsettings), I'm tring to do the same with `QMap<QString,int>`. I would like the configuration file to look like this:

```
1111=1  
2222=3  
4444=0
```

But I'm getting a compilation error:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QMap<QString,int>)

Warning C4002: too many actual parameters for macro 'Q_DECLARE_METATYPE'
ConfigSettings.h(5) : error C2976: 'QMap' : too few template arguments
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The error message you're getting is caused by the fact that the preprocessor doesn't know about templates. So it's parsing that macro call is if it had two arguments - `QMap<QString` and `int>`, which makes no sense.

To save the data as you want it, you're better of serializing it yourself to your `QSettings`. Something like this for writing:

```
settings.beginGroup("Whatever");
QMap<QString, int>::const_iterator i = map.constBegin();
while (i != map.constEnd()) {
     settings.setValue(i.key(), i.value());
     ++i;
 }
settings.endGroup();
```

To read the settings, use the same approach with the help of the `childKeys()` function.

```
settings.beginGroup("Whatever");
QStringList keys = settings.childKeys();
foreach (QString key, keys) {
     map[key] = settings.value(key).toInt();
}
settings.endGroup();
```

Answer (score 6):

Like [Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635608/mat) said, the error is caused by the preprocessor not understanding templates. However, you can easily fix this via a simple typedef.

```
typedef QMap<QString,int> QIntMap
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QIntMap)
```

Comment: This seems like a better answer for the more general case, though I understand why the selected answer was chosen for the QSettings specific situation.

Answer (score 3):

`QSetting` accept `QVariant` type to pass into `setValue` method, so it means that you can store `QMap<QString, QVarint>` map directly to settings

```
// Store
QMap<QString, QVariant> storeMap;
QMapIterator it(myMap);
// iterate through the map to save the values in your chosen format
while(it.hasNext())
{
    storeMap[it.key()] = QVariant(it.value());
    it.next();
}
settings.setValue("myKey", storeMap);

..
// Read
QMap<QString, QVariant> readMap = settings.value("myKey").toMap();
QMapIterator it(readMap);
while(it.hasNext())
{
    myMap[it.key()] = it.value().toInt();
    it.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand the accepted answer, but I think the original question was how to store the QMap.  It devolved into how to make the compiler behave.

```
QSettings mySettings...
QMapIterator it(myMap);
// iterate through the map to save the values in your chosen format
while(it.hasNext())
{
    it.next();
    mySettings.setValue(it.key(), it.value());
}
```

If however you wish to store this along with a bunch of other settings or data structures, you might consider using "beginGroup()" and "endGroup()" to group a bunch of different data structures into one file.  Very tidy and readable.

Comment: Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up instead of repeating the same information.