# QSetting<data type> for a QList

Tags: qt, qlist, qsettings

I have a QList of some non-primitive data type, say

```
QList <DockWidget*> tmp;
```

I want to store this whole list into settings, for writing and reloading, so that i don't lose my settings on restart.

I tried

```
settings.setValue("reference", tmp);
```

but get compilation error on reading

```
tmp = settings.value("reference");
```

How should I read and write such settings?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to save? You can't load and reuse pointers anyway.

Comment: i want the states of all widgets to be restored

Comment: @Roku I want my application to restore state of some widgets, from your statement, it seems i can't store and use pointers, which seems true. How to do that basically?

Comment: You should check if QMainWindow's [state storing feature](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#storing-state) already does what you need.

Comment: @Roku  actually i have some task that requires hiding and showing windows. when i hide and close the application, and then start the application and show, then i need the previously hidden windows

Answer (score 0):

That will not work. QSettings.setValue() operated around QVariant class, so before you can store things like

```
typedef QList<YouClass*> myListType;
```

you should implement all needed wrappers to convert myListTyoe to and from QVariant.

Comment: check this answer, it's explains everything you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452893/save-qlistint-to-qsettings

Comment: Check documentation regarding Q_DECLARE_METATYPE

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't make QSettings work with them - one must manually serialize/deserialize.

Comment: I know =), but I believe that answer to a question still should consider some homework =)